# How do I make sure my stupid edit never sees the light of day?

Tags: support

I was an idiot and edited an answer rather than [my question](https://askubuntu.com/users/145472/matthew-brown-aka-lord-matt) - how do I make sure my stupid edit never sees the light of day?

- [Question where I screwed up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360478/i-need-some-help-understanding-the-output-of-journalctl-as-it-relates-to-system)
- [Answer I accidentally vandalised](https://askubuntu.com/a/1361619/145472)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I rejected your [edit suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1167616) (hope it was the one you meant - the comment was a good clue), so the edit won't be applied :)

But in general, you've hit on a small problem - [there's no way to retract an edit suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-can-i-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-users-question-or-answer) as far as I know.

You can click the **Edit** button again and sort of undo your changes, but this is often tricky, especially if the text has formatting, so I don't recommend it unless the suggestion you made was very minor. Of course, this *is* the right action if you spotted a mistake in an otherwise good edit suggestion you've made (just not one you didn't actually want to make at all).

Another option is to ask someone to reject the edit - for example you could leave a comment for the post author asking them to reject your suggestion, or come to [the Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) or [Ask Ubuntu General Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ask folks there to reject.

Comment: To those wondering what the comment was: "*For goodness sake ignore my last edit. i am an idiot.*"

Comment: Thank you. I had a momentary BSoD moment when I saw that I had edited a perfectly fine answer instead of my question.

Comment: Why the [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1361619/revisions) look as if heynnema had "Update #1" (OP's edit) in their answer in the first place?

Comment: "Be careful" kinda works. Practically, one of the advantages of the suggested edit, and psudo-version control of rollback is that its semi trivial to fix - so one or two oops is unlikely to have a lasting effect

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog OP's suggestion accidentally removed the update #1 part I think

Comment: @Zanna You're probably right! It seemed to me that *this* was the OP's suggestion that they later wanted to remove, as it exists in both the question and the answer.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog ahaaa that helps to understand why the edit came to be accidentally suggested - I guess OP wanted to copy and paste that text from the answer into the question to give an update on what happened when they tried to follow the advice. That text in the question should probably be formatted as a quote - I'll do that

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt lol @ the BSoD moment... This is nothing - one day I should put together a list of my editing errors, including the one where I somehow made my entire edit with a non-Latin keyboard layout on without even noticing (thus filling some poor person's question with random characters), and the one where I replaced a link to an article about some Ubuntu thing with one to a video clip from *The Labyrinth* due to not checking what was in my clipboard XD